# Getting the UserName of an ApplicationUser into a view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display the name of an author of a question but unlike the other properties of the model, the ApplicationUser.UserName property does not show in the view (it's just blank). I am using Entity Framework, MVC 5 and Razor.

My **Question** model:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Created")]
    public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

My **QuestionController** Index action:

```
// GET: Questions
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Questions.ToList());
    }
```

And the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Waegogi.Models.Question>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Author.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreationDateTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rating)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.QuestionID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.QuestionID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.QuestionID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: may be you need applicationUser imports? and also instansiation of that class ?

Comment: Are you fetching Question through an ORM like nHibernate? It could be lazy lading the related property.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework, I have little experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by explicitly loading your relationships in your controller call:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View(db.Questions.Include(q => q.ApplicationUser).ToList());
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. The problem was my ignorance regarding lazy loading.